# test trough post displayed {} Node Js

Tags: node.js

i am created the hashpassword of node js registion form. i ran into the problem
i got the error was test trough post displayed {} using NodeJS. what i tried so far i attached below.please anyone solve the error

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const saveCustomer = async(req,res)=>{
    

        try {
      
        const hashedPassword =  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password); // 10 is the saltRounds

        const user = new userModel({
            name: req.body.name,
            address: req.body.address,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: hashedPassword,
            


        });


        await user.validate(); // Validate the input data
    
        await user.save();
        res.status(201).send({
          status: true,
          message: "user Created!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
        });
    
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error);
      }

}
```

i attached model also here

**Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

i attached image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues here:
Firstly reading from docs, bcrypt.hash is asynchronous. You either need to retrieve data as callback function or treat it as promise.
Also if we look into the official docs for bcrypt [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt?activeTab=readme#to-hash-a-password), if you use callback function, you also need to provide salt. Salt is basically random string that is used in hashing your password. It protects you from rainbow table attack.
As it seems when you do not use await on the function, it treats it as cb based approach and requires salt.
But if you are going to use promises like its described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt?activeTab=readme#to-hash-a-password), salt seems to be automatically generated. As it seems they left salt as required only for older implementations with cb for backward compatibility.

To answer your question, if you just add await your code should work properly automatically:

```
const hashedPassword =  await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password)
```

Comment: but record not added why

Comment: @JohnPeter Is hashed password generated correctly?

Comment: no i didn't get anything when i test trough post displayed {}  like this blank why

Comment: @JohnPeter and req.body.password is not empty value as well?

Comment: {
     
     "name" : "abvv",
     "address" : "aoora", 
   "username": "vbbb",
    "password" : 123
}

Comment: i attache model above

Comment: Just to confirm, where do you get {}.
Is it in hashedPassword variable or user variable after or just in general response. Need to know what each of these variables return

Comment: i attached image above what i tested through postman please look at the image.after that i checked on the database collection also collection didn't create it